# Transitioning from JS to React: How can I prepend an element and then remove it after some time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this small project I wrote in javascript and I'm trying to rewrite it using React. I have an Alert section where I prepend a message to so it appears at the top of the list, then gets removed after 5 seconds.

HTML:

```
<div id="alert-container">
    <button onclick="addAlert('alert')">Add</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function addAlert(message) {
    const alertContainer = document.getElementById("alert-container")

    const alert = document.createElement("div")
    alert.textContent = message
    alertContainer.prepend(alert)
    setTimeout(() => {
        alert.remove()
    }, 5000)
}
```

Where I'm stuck is I don't know how to "prepend" a React element. I could create a state that has a list of alert messages and then add a new  for every one of those, but I'm hit with two issues:

1. How to I set a timer to remove the actual React element after 5 seconds
2. How do I remove the message from the list of messages once it's time for it to be removed? I suppose I could add a `show:true` attribute and then set it to `false` after the timeout runs for each alert , but I am not sure if that is the ideal way to do this as it seems slightly over complicated.

I feel like this should be relatively simple to do like in the JS I have above, but I can't really find a simple way to do this. Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where I'm stuck is I don't know how to "prepend" a React element. I could create a state that has a list of alert messages and then add a new for every one of those

Yes, that's the way you'd do it. You'll have an array as your state, and then to prepend a new alert, you'll add to the front of that array.

> How to I set a timer to remove the actual React element after 5 seconds

You can set the timeout right after you make the change to the array

> How do I remove the message from the list of messages once it's time for it to be removed?

When the timer goes off, you'll set state and remove the alert from the array. Assuming the timers are all exactly 5 seconds your alert will have moved to the end of the array, so you can just remove the last element in the array.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const AlertContainer = () => {
  const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([]);

  const addAlert = (message) => {
    setAlerts(prev => [message, ...prev]);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlerts(prev => {
        const next = [...prev];
        next.pop();
        return next; 
      });
    }, 5000);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {alerts.map((message, i) => (
        <div key={i}>{message}</div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => addAlert('alert')}>Add</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

> One other question, if I wanted to fade these individual divs out, is there a React friendly way to do this?

For that you'll need a more complicated state. Now each alert is defined by two pieces of data: it's message, and whether it should be fading out or not. This also means that the last element in the array may not be ready to be removed from the page yet, so i'll add a unique id to each alert so i can find them in the array:

```
import { useState } from "react";

let uniqueId = 0;

const AlertContainer = () => {
  const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([]);

  const addAlert = (message) => {
    uniqueId += 1;
    const id = uniqueId;
    setAlerts((prev) => [{ id, message, fadeOut: false }, ...prev]);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlerts((prev) => {
        const next = [...prev];
        const i = next.findIndex((alert) => alert.id === id);
        next[i] = { ...next[i], fadeOut: true };
        return next;
      });
    }, 5000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {alerts.map((alert) => (
        <div
          key={alert.id}
          className={alert.fadeOut ? "fadeOut" : undefined}
          onTransitionEnd={() => {
            setAlerts((prev) => prev.filter((a) => a.id !== alert.id));
          }}
        >
          {alert.message}
        </div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => addAlert("alert")}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As the complexity grows, you may want to create a separate `<Alert>` component, and let it handle the extra pieces of state. For example, here i move the responsibility for the timer and the fade out logic into the child component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

let id = 0;

const AlertContainer = () => {
  const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([]);

  const addAlert = (message) => {
    id += 1;
    setAlerts((prev) => [{ id, message }, ...prev]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {alerts.map((alert) => (
        <Alert
          key={alert.id}
          message={alert.message}
          remove={() => {
            setAlerts((prev) => prev.filter((a) => a.id !== alert.id));
          }}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => addAlert("alert")}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Alert = ({ message, remove }) => {
  const [fadeOut, setFadeOut] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setFadeOut(true);
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className={fadeOut ? "fadeOut" : undefined}
      onTransitionEnd={remove}
    >
      {message}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Ah, that's where I went wrong. I was trying to create an individual <Alert /> element per message, instead of creating one container like you have. One other question, if I wanted to fade these individual divs out, is there a React friendly way to do this? In my JS example, I would add a CSS class and add a "transitionend" eventListener to the individual div but I'm not sure if there is a built in way to do this in React.

Comment: `if I wanted to fade these individual divs out, is there a React friendly way to do this?` Added an example of how that can be done.

Comment: Also added an example of splitting it up into two components.